# HTML5 Canvas toDataUrl - Upload gif workaround

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, gif

I'm wondering if it's possible to preview a .gif image within a canvas element and uploaded it as an 'image/gif' file type. I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf), but it incorrectly mentions .gif in the title but no references on how to deal with canvas and gifs within any of the responses/comments.

According to the docs, 'image/gif' is not an accepted type for `toDataUrl`. Is there a workaround / lib which will allow me to place a gif within a preview canvas and upload the canvas file as a gif?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### FileReader.readAsDataURL()

From [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

```js
function previewFile() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function() {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    preview.src = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()">
<br>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```