# How to use Canvas toDataURL("image/gif") to create a gif instead of PNG

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, gif

I'm having trouble getting my canvas to give me a gif that I can submit to a post.

When I run `toDataURL("image/gif")` and check the result, it is actually a PNG.

The image drawn was a jpeg originally.

Tested in chrome 58 and firefox 50.

Is there a trick to it? or do I need another library to convert it?

My goal is to try and save as much data as possible. I tested just using MS Paint and GIF over PNG saves about 30% (over the PNG the canvas created), and the images this is for are black and white, so no quality loss at all.

Thanks in advance for the help!

-Edit

That link doesn't explain how to get the canvas to give me a gif instead of a PNG.  Only how to read a data URL out of a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Canvas toDataUrl - Upload gif workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31280897/html5-canvas-todataurl-upload-gif-workaround)

Comment: That link doesn't explain how to get the canvas to give me a gif instead of a PNG. Only how to read a data URL out of a file.  The original drawn image is a jpeg or png.

Comment: You'll need an other lib, no browser I know do support natively exporting to gif.